# Getting a System.FormatException when using a decimal, it seems as though I shouldn't be

Tags: c#, exception

I am needing to make a "banking" program and I have it set up and working besides one problem. When trying to withdrawal more money than is in the account I keep getting a System.FormatException telling me "input string was not in correct format". I am using decimal variables and when I enter 101 for example into the textbox to withdraw from an account containing $100 I get the exception.

I am wanting to give the user a warning that they do not have enough funds and then revert the account amount to what it was before they tried to withdrawal into a negative amount. How could I go about this? I've looked online in many places but haven't found much help with the matter. Also please go easy on me I am still pretty new to programming.

ps. when depositing or withdrawing without going negative this is not an issue, the exception only occurs when the account goes negative.

```
if (amount < 0m)
        {
            amount += Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text); // this is where the error occurs 
            MessageBox.Show("invalid funds");
        }
```

full code here

```
 Decimal amount = 0.00m;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Deposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {

                //checks for a user input below or equal to 1000 and greater than 0
                if (Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text) <= 1000 && Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text) > 0)
                {
                    amount += Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                }
            else
            {
                {
                    // shows when ever a user trys to deposit anything other than a valid number
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter an amount between $0 - $1,000.");
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                }
            }
            }

            // catches exceptions when the user trys to deposit anything other than a valid number
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter an amount between $0 - $1,000.");
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
    }

    private void Account_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Format("$" + amount.ToString());
    }

    private void Withdrawal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            //checks for a user input below or equal to 1000
            if (Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text) <= 1000 && Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text) > 0)
            {
                amount -= Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                {
                    // shows when ever a user trys to withdrawal anything other than a valid number
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter an amount between $0 - $1,000.");
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }

        // catches exceptions when the user trys to withdrawal anything other than a valid number
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an amount between $0 - $1,000.");
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        //checks to see if the user has withdrawn the account below 0
        if (amount < 0m)
        {
            amount += Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("invalid funds");
        }
    }


    //clears the text box for a new entry when the user click on it
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: That is a weird description, because the line you posted should not generate an error on `101` regardless of money in the bank. The compiler does not know what you want to do with the number `101`, it only parses the text into a number. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Had you tried to parse a floating number string with as integer value, I would certainly understand your problem, but here, I do not understand because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance carefully and [edit] your post with all data necessary to demonstrate the issue. In this particular case there is no way to know what the value of `textBox1.Text` actually is (as there is some chance post is providing incomplete information when claiming " I enter 101")

Comment: Posting five lines of code totally out of context isn't useful. See [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your post to provide that MCVE and the exact error message you're getting, along with sample input. (And why are you using `Parse` instead of `TryParse`? What do you do if the user enters `abc` in the TextBox?)

Comment: You use textBox1.Text = "" in your code.  Then Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text), kaboom of course.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably not helping yourself by having textBox1 output dollar signs sometimes (`Account_Click`) but at other times it should **not** have a dollar sign (just numbers in `Withdrawal_Click`).

That kind of thing muddies the waters and makes not only the use of the application confusing but can also confuse you as you debug it - perhaps not in this situation, but as you write more complex programs.

The exception is happening because there is a character in the textbox that isn't valid for a decimal (I'm guessing it's the $).

What you want to do is when Visual Studio stops for the exception, mouse over "textBox1.Text" and see what it's value is, does it have a '$' or any spaces in it?

Comment: The textbox empties when I click on it to enter the amount to withdraw so I'm sure it wasn't the $ causing the issue (but who knows I could likely be wrong). But I have managed to get it working now by making a tempAmount variable, setting it equal to amount before the if (amount < 0) statement and then within the if statement setting amount = tempAmount. its allowing me to show a msgbox alerting the user of insufficient funds and keeping the previous amount in the account(its was previously withdrawing into a negative amount.)